# Showing $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ defined by $f(n)=n/1$ is not surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've been having a little difficulty in proving that certain functions are or are not surjective - particularly this example. Showing that the function is injective is quite straightforward, but I'm not quite understanding the processes for showing that this, $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ defined by $f(n)=n/1$, is not surjective.

I understand that for a mapping or function to be surjective, every element in the codomain should have some element in the domain in which $f$(element in domain)=element in codomain. In other words, if $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain, for all $b \in B$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Could someone briefly explain the proof for this example?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematical formulas; [here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Notice that $f(n)$ is always an integer. So, for example, if $b = 1/2$, then there is no $a$ with $f(a) = b$.

Comment: There is no $n$ that is sent to 1/2? Are you sure this is the posed question? Why even bother writing the "over 1 part" (for the question inventor)?

Comment: @DavidP by definition an element of $\mathbb Q$ is of the form $m/n$, where $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. Just for the visual, I guess.

Comment: @AlvinLepik That is one definition of Q, not "the" definition of Q

Comment: @DavidP and I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $p/q \in \mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb Z$ and assume $gcd(p,q)=1$. If $f(k) = k/1 = p/q$, then $p=kq$, a contradiction.

Effectively, you're asking if every rational is an integer. Clearly, that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Take, for example, the number $1/2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. If $f$ was surjective, then there would exist an element $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{n}{1} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, you have $n \cdot 2 = 1$, where $n$ is a natural number, but this is impossible since $n = \frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{N}$. So we have a contradiction and the function $f$ is not surjective.